# postgresql column referencing issue

Tags: postgresql, join

Facing trouble related to column referencing.detailed problem below 
Say I have 2 tables Table Metadata and Table Transactions

Table `Metadata` has the following information regarding columns

```
Attribute   Value   desc
EmpID      123456   employee of the month
Name        XYZ     defaulter
```

The Table Structure of the `Transactions` table is as follows:

```
EmpID   Name  Type  Title
0       ABC    A        …
1       DEF    A        …
2       GHI    A        …
3       JKL    A        …
12345   XYZ    A        …
```

I want to be able to join such that I get the resultset as

```
EmpID   Name  Type  Title  desc
0       ABC    A        …
1       DEF    A        …
2       XYZ    A        …  defaulter
3       JKL    A        …
12345   PQR    A        …  employee of the month
```

How can I achieve this? I am using postgresql. So I do understand that I have to use information schema, but confused about the joins. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want,

```
SELECT t.*, coalesce( m1.desc, m2.desc ) AS desc
FROM transactions AS t
LEFT OUTER JOIN metadata AS m1
  ON (m1.attribute = 'Name' AND t.name = m1.value )
LEFT OUTER JOIN metadata AS m2
  ON (m2.attribute = 'EmpID' AND t.empid = m2.value );
```

What we do is join twice once for each join condition.